# Can I rent a multipurpose server for gaming and web hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, server, webserver

I am thinking about renting a server.
The problem is, there aren't just "servers", like one would build at home, there are game servers, web servers, etc.

Now the first question would be: can I rent a combined web and game server? Because if that's possible, I did not find anything on the internet about such service.

If I would need a separate web server, that's still okay, but then there are some other problems about the game server part. Normal hosting services may give you the possibility to host a server for a certain game, like Minecraft. But that's it. No switching options, just ONE type of server. And if you want another type of game server, rent another one. But I would need to switch between several games.

Also, normally you get some kind of interface to interact with the server. I don't like that method either, because I sometimes need more control over things I can't control in the control panels there.

I would really like to just host a server at home, but my bandwidth kind of kills that dream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A server is defined by what is installed on it.  There are "game servers" and "web servers" because they come with the correct software pre-installed and pre-configured.

There is no reason that you couldn't get a server "like one would build at home" and install and manage your own software on it.   Such a beast is usually referred to as a "virtual private server" (VPS) or a "dedicated server".   With a VPS, you share a physical machine with other users and you get a virtual box.  A dedicated server is more expensive, but it is an actual machine to which you have full access.

Comment: Thanks for the info so far and the edit.
I think a VPS would suffice for my purpose then. I don't think i need a completely separate dedicated server.
And it looks like they aren't that expensive either